# How to take user input as argument of function in JavaScript in order to implement Insertion Sort Algorithm?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Below is the function for insertion sort. I want that user should give the input from html form as an array elements instead of hard coding the elements of array. I have tried several techniques but in vain.

```
function insertionSort (inputArr) {
    let length = inputArr.length;
    for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        let key = inputArr[i];
        let j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && inputArr[j] > key) {
            inputArr[j + 1] = inputArr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        inputArr[j + 1] = key;
    }
    return inputArr;
};

    let inputArr = [2,4,5,36,2,6,26,8,3,7]; // I want here user input which comes from html form instead of hard-coding elements of array like this
    insertionSort(inputArr);
    console.log(inputArr);
```

// Event listner

```
function getData() {
let userData = document.getElementById('data').value;
return userData;
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
<title>Insertion Sort In JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Insertion Sort in JavaScript</h1>
<form action="#">
    <label for="data">Write Random Numbers</label>
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button onclick="getData()">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="printData"></div>

<script src="insertionsort.js"></script>
```

Comment: Window.prompt() maybe

Comment: `input.split(separator).map(Number)`?

Comment: I have tried this but not working.
`function getData() {
    let dataArray = [];
    let userData = document.getElementById('data').value.split(",").map(Number);
    dataArray.push(userData);
    return dataArray;
}`

Comment: @Code-lover well, simply return `userData`, what it the dataArray for?

Comment: @appleapple still not working

Comment: "I have tried this but not working" - it would need to be inside an event listener.  Can you please edit the question to include the HTML and the listener.

Comment: @James please check it now

Comment: Your getData function shouldn't return anything.  Can you try calling the insertionSort from within getData?

Comment: **@James** you were right. I did the same and it works fine but there is little confusion in the code. could you please check it for me. `function getData() {
    
    let dataArray = [];
    let userData = document.getElementById('data').value;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
            dataArray.push(userData[i]);
    }
        let inputArr = dataArray;
        insertionSort(inputArr);
        alert(inputArr);

}
`